# How to get output of STDOUT to GCP cloud logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, cloud, devops, gcp

Hey I have a job running on a gcp VM where some imported libraries are logging to stdout with the print or python logging library, and I also have written a lot of code where the output is logged to stdout with the python logging library (e.g. `logging.info("*** INFO ***")` ). I'm running into an issue where the logs are printing to STDOUT but not sent to GCP cloud logging. I have tried so many things such as installing the logging agent on the VM, going through a bunch of GCP docs, using deprecated logging libraries, etc, but nothing has worked. Here are some examples:

`gcp_log_example.py` - The `'HI'` log get sent to GCP cloud logging but none of the logs in `builtin_logger.py`. This is why I cannot use this approach.

```
import subprocess
import google.cloud.logging
import logging

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()
logging.info('HI')

subprocess.run('python3 builtin_logger.py', shell=True)
```

^^ I will not use this approach because I'm pretty sure it requires me to go through every library and integrate GCP logging. No way anyone is going to do that.

`builtin_logger.py`

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
print('*** print! ***')
logging.info('*** INFO! ***')
logging.warning('*** WARNING! ***')
logging.critical('*** CRITICAL! ***')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

^ These logs get sent to stdout but are not sent to GCP.

I've also tried running it like this but in this case the severity level is not captured but the logs are sent to GCP cloud logging (twice though --- the logs are duplicated)

`tmp.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 builtin_log.py 2>&1 | logger -t "builtin_log.py"
```

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker-compose up --build | logger 2>&1
```

^ this is basically what I want but the only problem with this is it doesn't capture the severity.

tl;dr: I need to get logs from STDOUT on GCP VM sent to GCP cloud logging. Is this even the right approach?

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you installed Google logging and the `stdout` is going to `syslog`, then the logging agent is not configured correctly. Edit your post and include `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf`. More details here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration#syslog_configuration

Comment: Perhaps your VM cannot write to Cloud Logging. Add the output from this command to your post: `curl --silent --connect-timeout 1 -f -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes`. Run the command from the VM OS.

Comment: There are two agents for logging. Ops Agent and the legacy logging agent. My first comment is for the legacy logging agent, which is still used a lot. If you are using Ops Agent, a logging receiver must be correctly configured. More details here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent/configuration#logging-receivers

Comment: Hey thanks @JohnHanley, but unfortunately even after creating a new VM / installing ops agent I'm unable to see logs from STDOUT in gcp cloud logging. The simplest `.py` script `logging.info('hi')` doesn't work. Following here: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation - it works if I use pip `google-cloud-logging` library. This isn't an option since 3rd party packages do not use `google-cloud-logging`. The cmd in your 2nd comment shows it's working, and this command shows everything is running properly: `sudo systemctl status google-cloud-ops-agent"*"`

Comment: I don't have any more ideas. I do not have a similar problem with any of my VMs. It appears that the issue is with the OS logging. Where are the logs from your program going and what is the logging level? Once you know where the log entries are going, you can configure Google Ops Agent to log the contents of that file or adjust the capture level.

Comment: @JohnHanley Maybe there's something fundamentally wrong with what I'm doing? My steps are `create VM instance` (install ops agent) -> create `tmp.py` file with the super simple logging code (same as above) -> run `python tmp.py` and it logs `INFO:root:info` to the screen (stdout). Anything obvious you think I'm missing?

Comment: OK - that helped. When you run a program in your terminal, the default destination for the Python logger is `stdout`, which is your screen. If you want the output gong someplace else, you must configure that in your program. I though you were running a program as a service which does not have a terminal (tty) which means `stdout` goes to the logging system. Your first sentence said `job` which I interpreted to mean a service.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So typically I would deploy a real application via docker and have it run on schedule (e.g. an ELT process). I haven't ever really dug into GCP, but as a newbie I started a VM, typed `screen` -> `sudo docker-compose up --build > docker_logs_$(date +%s).log`. I thought the logs output into the docker logs would get sent to gcp cloud logging, but I guess not. So 2 questions: 1). How can I get logs from this approach to get sent to cloud logging? And 2). How would you properly deploy it to production not using my scrappy approach?

Comment: In your example, the logs are being stored **inside** the Docker container. Review the Docker flag `--log-driver`. However, I don't know the equivalent for Docker Compose. Check this [link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) and this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/archived/docker-gcplogs-driver/index.md#configuring-the-google-cloud-logging-driver-for-a-single-container) and this [link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/)

Comment: The first part of my last comment might be wrong. If you run containers using Docker Compose and do not specify detached (-d), then the output is going to the terminal. You are sending the terminal output to the file `docker_logs_$(date +%s).log`. There is nothing to send to Cloud Logging. If you want the contents of that file logged to Cloud Logging, then you must configure a receiver to handle that.

Comment: I think your confusion arises from not understanding Python logging. If you are adding Docker, then you must understand Docker logging as well. Once you have your Python logging going someplace, then you can configure Cloud Logging to do something with that data. For the most popular logging destinations, Cloud Logging already handles them. For the most part, default Python logging is nothing more than a fancy print statement to your terminal (stdout). Cloud Logging does not handle terminal (tty) style stdout print statements. Only when those log entries are sent to a destination.

Comment: Hey thanks again. OK so let's just ignore docker for now. I just want to get the default python logging output (stdout) to get sent (and received) from gcp VM -> gcp cloud logging. I don't want to reconfigure any python code, let alone any logging code that other packages use. Working with devops, they are somehow able to get all logs from python default logging library (e.g. `print('<text>')` or `logging.warning('<warning>')`) sent to a cloud logging tool (including logs from 3rd party packages). I am trying this out on one of my side projects so I don't have access to a devops person.

Comment: The problem is not with Cloud Logging. You do not have logging at all for your program. The way you are running your program sends logging to the terminal. If you want it going elsewhere, you must modify your program or send the program's output to a logger process. The reason DevOps has logging is they configured the program to run as a background process or as a service capturing the program output (stdout). Again that is not a Google Cloud Logging issue. Is is a problem that you must configure for your environment. You log to the OS logs and then Cloud Logging picks up those entries.

Comment: For example on Ubuntu you can run a program like this: `my_program | logger 2>&1`. That examples sends `stdout` and `stderr` to the OS logger. See this [link](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/logger.1.html).

Comment: As a suggestion, I recommend learning about Python logging, logging daemons, logging programs and logging targets (processes and files). I think you do not understand the basics. For example you seem to be confused on why sending logs to the terminal does not result in Cloud Logging recording them.

Comment: Hey you're right. I did learn a little bit more about logging. At this point I don't see an easy way to extract logs with severity from running a python app on a VM where logs are sent to stdout -> gcp cloud logging (or any cloud logging tool for that matter). For now as an MVP I guess I'll just run `sudo docker-compose up | logger 2>&1`. This is almost exactly what I want. The only problem with this solution is it doesn't log severity. I think I may be also going down the wrong rabbit hole. I might need to redirect my learning into production deployment + CI/CD.